# PHP Regex extract everything except newlines and tabs

Tags: php, regex

I know this kind of question is asked really often, but all the other answers don't really work for me. I have the following block of text:

```
"""
\n
\t\t\t\t\tÁrea útil\n
\t\t\t\t\t\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t150 m²\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n
\t\t\t\t\t\n
\t\t\t\t
"""
```

And I want to ignore all newlines and tabs (`\n` and `\t`), and extract everything else to an array. So ideally, for example, the text block above would be transformed into

```
[
    'Área útil',
    '150m²',
]
```

EDIT: Here are some examples of what I've tried:

```
(?!\n)(?!\t)[.]+
(?!\n)(?!\t)(.)+
(\r\n)+|\r+|\n+|\t+
^\w+$
```

EDIT2: Sorry about that, completely forgot to mention the language was PHP

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can do:

```
<?php
$string = "\n
\t\t\t\t\tÁrea útil\n
\t\t\t\t\t\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t150 m²\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n
\t\t\t\t\t\n
\t\t\t\t";

// Get rid of the tabs
$string = preg_replace( '/(\t)/m', '', $string );

// Split on new lines
$array = preg_split( '/[\r\n]/m', $string );

// Loop the array and get rid of empty strings
foreach( $array as $k=>$v )
{
    if( $v === '' )
    {
        unset( $array[ $k ] );
    }
}

// Re-index the array
$array = array_values( $array );

var_dump( $array );
```

Which outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Área útil"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "150 m²"
}
```

Comment: I tried that and literally every character was a match